# Is there a way to work with FileManager and NSBundle to get all the applications that support a given type of file in the /Applications directory?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm creating a Commandline tool that will get an input from a user to search for a specific application that supports a certain file extension. For example, if I enter mp4, it will probably show me QuickTime. I'm looking for the specific FileManager manipulation to achieve this in Swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`NSWorkspace.urlForApplication(toOpen:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1533391-urlforapplication). It finds the application that would be opened if you had double clicked on a file, and returns its URL. Since it requires a file to work, you need to first create a temporary empty file somewhere, with the desired extension, then call this method.

```
let tempFileURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("foo.mp4")
FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: tempFileURL.path, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
// this gives me the URL for QuickTime Player:
// file:///System/Applications/QuickTime%20Player.app/
let url = NSWorkspace.shared.urlForApplication(toOpen: tempFileURL)
```